# indexPath.row for whole tableview, not only section?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a tableView wich displays content from an array with objects. But the tableview have sections for each date, and I get the same content in all the sections. I guess `NSDictionary *object = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` returns the row for the section and not for the total array. How can I get the row count for the whole tableView? Or is it some other way to do it?

Comment: can u show me line where u retrieve data in cellForRow, numberOfrowsInsection?

Comment: You are correct, `indexPath.row` is the row inside the section `indexPath.section`. Depending on how your data is structured, you can probably sum up the row numbers of the sections that come before `indexPath.section` and add `indexPath.row` to that.

Comment: Well, I'll try to explain how the data is set up.
So I have my array with NSDictionaries in it. And I have another array with titles and and number of rows for that title.
So in numberOfRowsInSection I have this,`[[[titles objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Values"] count]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int rowsOffset = 0;
for (int section; section ++; section < indexPath.section) {
  rowsOffset += [[[titles objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Values"] count];
}

NSDictionary *object = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+rowOffset];
```

probably better:

```
NSArray *theArray = [[titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Values"];
NSDictionary *object = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't do it the other way. Because I don't have the whole object in titles. But the first way worked.